# How to render Google chart pdf file using wicked pdf rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf, google-chat, wkhtmltopdf-binary

Application setup is rails 4 & wicked pdf.
how to render pie chart using google chart in my pdf file?

Comment: render as html and then generate as pdf. ?

Comment: @SudiptaMondal yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution on this at https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/issues/255#issuecomment-645453114

I think you need to tell wkhtmltopdf to wait for you to be ready.